# Clickable text is not added after verifying that groupedData[groupName] exists and is an array with a length greater than 2

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to implement a clickable text called `Mostra tutti` (Show all) if the number of arrays is greater than 2 - in other words, if I have more of 2 array inside `username` datatable column cell I want to see `Mostra tutti` to show/hide all array inside that specific cell
Look at this picture

[image]

You can test a live version [HERE](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/). Choose 'manga' radio button and then press "Raggruppa" button.

What's the problem? I expect, for that cell that has a number of arrays greater than 2, to see the clickable text "Show all" but this does not appear in place of the arrays for that specific cell

How am I trying to solve this problem?

I added a validation to ensure that there are no more than 2 arrays in the username cell before adding the "Show all" button.. Here the relevant code:

```
function showAllRowsInCell(cell, content, groupName) {
    console.log("grouped:", grouped);
    console.log("groupedData[" + groupName + "].length:", groupedData[groupName] ? groupedData[groupName].length : "undefined");
    var modifiedContent = removeMarkers(content);

    if (grouped && groupedData[groupName] && groupedData[groupName].length > 2) {
        var showAllButton = $('<button class="show-all-button">Mostra tutti</button>');
        $(cell).html(modifiedContent).append(showAllButton);

        showAllButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(cell).html(modifiedContent);
        });
    } else {
        $(cell).html(modifiedContent);
    }
}

// ...

// After initializing the DataTable, call showAllRowsInCell for the cells 'Username'
if (grouped && groupedData) {
    $('.grouped-mode tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
        var cell = this;
        var rowIndex = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).index();
        var groupName = dataTable.row(rowIndex).data().id.match(/[^\d\s]+/)[0];
        var groupItems = groupedData[groupName];
        if (groupItems && groupItems.length > 2) {
            showAllRowsInCell(cell, groupItems.map(function(item) { return item.username; }).join('<br>'), groupName);
            // Add log points here to verify the values
            console.log("cell:", cell);
            console.log("content:", groupItems.map(function(item) { return item.username; }).join('<br>'));
            console.log("groupName:", groupName);
        }
    });
}
```

But despite my trying the clickable text "Mostra tutti" is not displayed for that type of cells.I can't understand what the problem could be
[Here](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/static/script.js) the entire javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `$('.grouped-mode tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(`) is executed, the table hasn't been rendered yet and so the jQuery selector can't find anything.

Datatables, in *columnDefs* section, allows to assign a callback *"createdCell
"* to manipulate the cell rendering.
I noticed also that the *groupedData* already contains a *showLinks* flag which is true when more than 2 username links are present.

Combining these informations, I suggest to:

- remove the block which contains `$('.grouped-mode tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(`
- add in the grouped Datatables definition the callback:

```js
dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({

    "data": tableData,

    //....

    "columnDefs": [{

        "targets": 2,

        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {

            if (!rowData.showLinks)
                return;

            const showAllButton = $('<button class="show-all-button">Mostra tutti</button>');
            showAllButton.on('click', () => {alert('ciao')});
            $(td).append(showAllButton);
        }
    }]
});
```

`"targets": 2` is the *<td>* index that we want to modify.

I have not completely understood the purpose of the button, so in the example I have simplified it with an *alert()*

[Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) the documentation about *columns.createdCell*

### Additional informations

Let's clarify the situation: in your code you have two versions of Datatables: one that is displayed by default, which we will call **not grouped** and another that is displayed when the `Raggruppa` button is pressed *(it's the first one in your code, the one included in the `if (grouped) {` statement)* and which we will call **grouped**.

The *columnDefs* section that I suggested should only be inserted in the **grouped** Datatables.
However, if you used exactly the code I indicated, since there is:

```js
if (!rowData.showLinks)
   return;
```

the button will never appear in the **not grouped** version because its data does not have the *showLinks* key.

---

Your function *showAllRowsInCell()* that you have posted here is a bit buggy because it calls a *removeMarkers()* function that is not defined (is not present in [the entire javascript code](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/static/script.js)), also the *onclick* event handler of the button uses a *modifiedContent* variable that will be out of scope when the event will be fired.

Now that you've added some images in the comments, I think I understand what you want to achieve with the button, so the overall definition for the **grouped** Datatable could be:

```js
dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({

    "data": tableData,
    
    "columns": [
        {"data": "checkbox"},
        {"data": "id"},
        {"data": "username"},
        {"data": "extra"}
    ],

    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 100, 500],

    "columnDefs": [{

        "targets": 2,

        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {

            if (!rowData.showLinks)
                return;

            $(td).html('<div style="display:none">' + cellData + '</div>');

            const showAllButton = $('<button class="show-all-button">Mostra tutti</button>');

            showAllButton.on("click", (e) => {

                const btn = $(e.target);

                btn.siblings('div').css("display", "block");
                btn.css("display", "none");
            });

            $(td).append(showAllButton);
        }
    }]
});
```

Bear in mind that all this is a little more than what was asked for in the initial question

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but the `Mostra tutti` button is shown to me for all cells in the `Mostra tutte le righe mode` (i.e. when I initialize the table), but this shouldn't happen: it should only appear to me after I press I press the `Raggruppa button`. Not only that, but in the Raggruppa mode it should only appear if there are more than 2 elements, that is, if I have 3 text elements in the cell, then only in that case should the `Mostra tutti button` appear. Also, I don't know why, but I also get these clustered errors: `grouped false` ,
 `rowData.showLinks: Undefined`

Comment: **I have not completely understood the purpose of the button, so in the example I have simplified it with an alert()** - look [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/6MdbQIL.png) to understand what I try to do - you can also view a live version of your code implementation but you can see the problem that I described, look also [HERE](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/)

Comment: I've added informations based on the comments to my answer

Comment: Now I saw my mistake, I was defining the cells creation in the second part after `} else {
dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
"date": date,` when instead I should have defined in the first part and that is    `dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
   
    "data": tableData,`